# How many setTimeouts can you set?

Tags: node.js, settimeout, upperbound

I was writing a server side job that was trying to throttle an operation by doing the following:

```
var throttle = 1000 / 20;
for (var i = 0; i < 80000; i++) {
    setTimeout(operation, Math.floor(throttle * i));
}
```

I recognize that sleep works better here, but node.js required a library so I tried to tough it out. However, this program would work for over a thousand of these things, and then... nothing. No error message, just nothing happening. I suspect that JS ran out of timeout slots.

I have since migrated to sleep, which appears to be working, but I am curious as hell as to how JS is dealing with the timeouts. Does anyone have any additional insight?

Thanks!

For what it's worth, I assume that the answer is in this file https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/src/timer_wrap.cc assuming it's not in V8 itself.

Comment: It's definitely not V8 as `setTimeout` isn't a JavaScript language feature.

Comment: I'm not sure why your test hung ... it's still ticking :) away on my machine. I'd guess it's operating system dependent. This was my tiny change to your code so it was doing something visibly: `var throttle = 1000 / 20;
for (var i = 0; i < 80000; i++) {
    (function(i) {
        setTimeout((function(){
            console.log(i + " ticked! " + new Date().toLocaleTimeString());
        }), Math.floor(throttle * i));
    })(i);
}`

Comment: What is `operation`?  Your code works fine for me.

Comment: Operation was just printing console.log for me.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use `setInterval(function, interval)` instead?

```
var throttle = 1000 / 20;
var i = 0;
var interval = setInterval(function() { 
        operation();
        if(i++ == 80000) {
            // we're done
            clearInterval(interval); 
        }
    }, Math.floor(throttle * i));
```

(correcting, of course, for any off-by-one I've introduced)